# How to reduce repeated HCL code in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have some Terraform code like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file1" {
  key    = "someobject1"
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.examplebucket.id}"
  source = "./src/index.php"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file2" {
  key    = "someobject2"
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.examplebucket.id}"
  source = "./src/main.php"
}

# same code here, 10 files more
# ...
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform supports loops via the [`count` meta parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count) on resources and data sources.

So, for a slightly simpler example, if you wanted to loop over a well known list of files you could do something like the following:

```
locals {
  files = [
    "index.php",
    "main.php",
  ]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "files" {
  count  = "${length(local.files)}"
  key    = "${local.files[count.index]}"
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.examplebucket.id}"
  source = "./src/${local.files[count.index]}"
}
```

Unfortunately Terraform's AWS provider doesn't have support for the equivalent of `aws s3 sync` or `aws s3 cp --recursive` although there is an [issue tracking the feature request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/3020).

Comment: Would you not also need a `count = "${length(local.files)}"` in the second resource?

Comment: @MattSchuchard thanks, entirely missed that while posting from the train this morning. Derp.